# Cannot define A8 on the Arduino Environment

Tags: c, arduino

I am currently working on a school project, and I am trying to define 12 photocells. For the first 8 sensors, nothing is wrong, but the 9th one does not work for some reason. 
Here is my code:

```
const int analogInPin_0 = A0;
const int analogInPin_1 = A1;
const int analogInPin_2 = A2;
const int analogInPin_3 = A3;
const int analogInPin_4 = A4;
const int analogInPin_5 = A5;
const int analogInPin_6 = A6;
const int analogInPin_7 = A7;
const int analogInPin_8 = A8;
```

Every analogInPin I try to define after A8 (including it) does not work for some reason. It always gives me an error saying:

'A8 was not declared in this scope'.

What is the problem?

Comment: What defines A0..A7?  Does that place define A8..A11?  Is the problem that it is an 8-bit connector so you don't have pins for connections 8-11?

Comment: I am using a mega Arduino so there should be 16 analog pins. So I'm guessing they should work. For some reason it doesn't in my situation.

Comment: I'm fine with 'there should be 16 pins'.  You need to find out how to get A8 defined.  I'd go about that by tracking which headers you include, and then find the one that defines A0-A7, and look to see what it takes to make it define A8-A15 (though you're only immediately interested in A8-A11).  I can't help further — I've not used Arduino at all.

Comment: Did you correctly set the target board as `Arduino Mega ...` in `Tools -> Board` menu of Arduino IDE?

Comment: Oh wow... that did the trick I think. Thanks so much!! I can't believe it was just that haha.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same thing happened to me. After long wasted hours, I decided to try the code on my Uno. Only then I realized that the board was selected as Uno while I was trying on my Mega. Changed the board to Mega and viola, everything worked perfectly.